# Instantiate the delegate pattern one time or more in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I am studying delegate pattern for swift on below code. I can not be pretty sure how can I use this option "without the need to reinstantiate the view.

```
protocol ShapeViewDelegate {
    func drawShapeView(_ shapeView: ShapeView)
}

class ShapeView: UIView {
    var strokeColor: UIColor?
    var fillColor: UIColor?
    
    var delegate: ShapeViewDelegate? {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        delegate?.drawShapeView(self) // self means object( ShapeView() ) is it instantiated ?
    }
}
```

---

View object supposed to ready coming from delegate object but I didn't instantiate it, where this object instantiated using protocol automatically instantiated it at the run time. So I am writing an example like this :

```
class ShapeViewController: ShapeViewDelegate {
drawShapeView(view)
}
```

View is instantiated in other words occupied the memory at this example ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `drawShapeView()` in `ShapeViewController`. In your code you are using or calling `drawShapeView()` which is already being called in your `ShapeView`. And about instantiate, yes you need to instantiate `ShapeView` in `ShapeViewController` or any other place you are confirming the delegate.

Code in your `ShapeViewController` -

```
class ShapeViewController: ShapeViewDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    
      super.viewDidLoad()
  
      let shape = ShapeView(...)
      shape.delegate = self
      view.addSubView(shape)
   }

   func drawShapeView(_ shapeView: ShapeView) {
      //your code here
   }
}
```

Via this feature, you can have many definitions of `ShapeView` based on different `ShapeViewController` instances without worrying to modify `ShapeView`.